# Get return URL on Custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom `Authorize` attribute to handle `LogIn`. And I need to redirect user to last page after login. For example :

Product Controller

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Detail(int productID)
{
     //code here
     return View(model);
}
```

Let's say user isn't logged in when he tried to access `Product/Detail/msi-gtx-970`, my web application will redirect the user to `LogIn` page. I want to redirect user back to `Product/Detail/msi-gtx-970` after successful `LogIn`. How to do that?

My LogIn Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    //code here
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogIn(string returnUrl)
{
    //code here

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        return View("Index", "Home");
    }

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's what happens by default. Have a look at the code in the AccountController when you create a new app in VS (it uses a returnUrl parameter)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I checked the default template `LogIn` method from `AccountController`, it has `string returnUrl` in GET method, so I tried adding `public ActionResult LogIn(string returnUrl)` inside my GET method but it's always null aka not working.

Comment: You need to study all the associated code to see how it works

Comment: @StephenMuecke: The problem is ASP Identity is suppose to create a `QueryString["returnUrl"]` everytime user hit a LogIn page for example : `localhost:12345/Account/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2FCart` but I didn't get anything even if it comes from `non authorized` request. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to receive the returnUrl on your get Action;

```
       [AllowAnonymous]
       public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
       {
           ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
           return View();
       }
```

Change your form on the "Login "view passing the url as parameter for posting the url value:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
....
 }
```

the rest of your code is fine

Answer (score 0):

in your customeAuthorizer attribute you should have the **filterContext** object and then you can use the following code sample.

```
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Please Provide authToken";
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "Authentication",
                    action = "Login",
                    errorMessage = "Invalid Resourse Access Attempt",
                    ReturnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value
                }));
```

or you can use the following function for this purpose as well.

```
public void AuthFailed(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Please Provide authToken";
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "Authentication",
                    action = "Login",
                    errorMessage = "Invalid Resourse Access Attempt",
                    ReturnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value
                })); 
    }
```

and in your login (GET) action you can handle it like this.

```
TempData["ReturnUrl"] = Request.Query["returnUrl"].ToString();
```

and after the successfull login (when the user successfully logged in) you gotta redirect it to the same requested page. Login (POST)

```
               if (TempData["ReturnUrl"] != null)
                {
                    string[] temp = TempData["ReturnUrl"].ToString().Split('/');
                    if (temp.Length == 3)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(temp[1], temp[0], new { id = temp[2] });
                    }
                    else if (temp.Length == 1)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(temp[1], temp[0]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```