# ReturnUrl parameter in Login url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an application using MVC 5. I have written code for login functionality. When I tried to launch application, Login page is getting added with a query string parameter **ReturnUrl**. Here is my code:

```
            public ActionResult Login()
            {
                var authentication = Authentication;
                if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
                {
                    //code for user validation
                }

                return View();
            }
```

I'm unable to find the code that is adding ReturnUrl parameter to url. Can anyone help me, where I can find code that adds ReturUrl parameter?

Comment: Check the AccountController.cs in Controllers folder of you project

Comment: Code snippet displayed above is copied from AccountController.cs. But I'm unable to find any code related to ReturnUrl there.

Comment: Getting detailed to issue: I have created a page for ForgetPassword and I have added link for login page there. When I redirect back to login page, no ReturnUrl parameter is added to url. @Html.ActionLink("Go to Login page", "Login", "Account"), I have used this code for creating a link to login page in ForgetPassword page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `AuthorizeAttribute` class is part of `System.Web.Mvc` namespace (see Github repository: [aspnetwebstack](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/tree/master/src/System.Web.Mvc)). The method leads to login redirection there is `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`:

```
protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // Returns HTTP 401 - see comment in HttpUnauthorizedResult.cs.
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

HTTP 401 status code response from method above will trigger `FormsAuthenticationModule` (see reference below), where `OnLeave` method redirects to login URL with `FormsAuthentication.ReturnUrlVar` property included:

```
strRedirect = loginUrl + "?" + FormsAuthentication.ReturnUrlVar + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strUrl, context.Request.ContentEncoding);

// Do the redirect
context.Response.Redirect(strRedirect, false);
```

To override this behavior (including remove `ReturnUrl` part), create an authorization class extends from `AuthorizeAttribute` class, e.g. (this is an example implementation):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // @Override
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { controller = "Account", 
                  action = "Login"
                }));
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you may implement custom authorization attribute like this one:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]
public ActionResult UserPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

NB: Use `AuthorizeAttribute` on all pages that requires user login authentication, for login page use `AllowAnonymousAttribute` instead.

Related references:

[System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule (MS Github reference)](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationModule.cs)

[What initially sets the ReturnUrl parameter when using AuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305962/what-initially-sets-the-returnurl-parameter-when-using-authorizeattribute)

[Generate a return Url with a custom AuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800361/generate-a-return-url-with-a-custom-authorizeattribute)

[How to remove returnurl from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716153/how-to-remove-returnurl-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

It's a default behavior of asp.net authentication. The "returnUrl" is added when you try to access a private url. If you want to remove that you will need a custom implementation of authorize class.

Comment: where can I find authorize class?

Comment: `AuthorizeAttribute` class by default is part of System.Web.Mvc namespace, you may create authorization class which extends from `AuthorizeAttribute` for custom authorization functionality.

Comment: That's what i talking about, i where share my code but Tetsuya Yamamoto already shared.

Comment: Thanks for the response