# Is it possible to change query string arguments on AccessDeniedPath?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app, I can change the target route for unauthorised requests in my `Startup.cs` like so:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
{
    o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
});
```

That will return `/Home/Error?ReturnUrl=...` where `...` is whatever page I was trying to access.

But I actually just want it to return simply "/Home/Error?code=401"

I tried e.g.

```
o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error?code=401"
```

but that brings back simply

```
"/Home/Error?code=401?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin"
```

I then realised there's a `ReturnUrlParameter` in the options, like this:

```
o.ReturnUrlParameter = "code";
o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
```

which gets me this far in the redirect:

```
/Home/Error?code=%2FAdmin
```

But I want to specify the keyvalue value (e.g. 401), i.e. replace the page the request came from, so the final result would be

```
/Home/Error?code=401
```

Comment: You may have an issue with the Roles on the Server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: @jdweng that has nothing to do with what I want to achieve. My authorisations are working fine, I just want to change the page it redirects to when a user is unauthorised. That link is also for ASP.NET 3.5 whereas I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: That seems to be a default behavior and it is there for a reason. Perhaps, just ignore it if you don't use it on server. If you still wish to remove it, may try something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35364588) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49657353). May be this cannot be achieved without custom auth implementation. [See discussion here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1682)

Comment: I actually have a custom auth routine running, but I've just realised I can basically check to see if `ReturnUrl` is not empty on my `Home/Error` request and do what I need there, so now longer necessary to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code, it seems that you are using cookie Authentication, I suggest yo could try to change the redirect URL using the [CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnRedirectToAccessDenied Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onredirecttoaccessdenied?view=aspnetcore-5.0), check the following sample code:

```
        services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthentication")
            .AddCookie("CookieAuthentication", config =>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie"; // Name of cookie     
                config.LoginPath = "/Login/UserLogin"; // Path for the redirect to user login page    
                config.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/UserAccessDenied";
                config.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ctx =>
                    {
                        var redirectPath = ctx.RedirectUri;
                        if (redirectPath.Contains("?ReturnUrl"))
                        {
                            //remove the ReturnURL
                            var url = redirectPath.Substring(0, redirectPath.LastIndexOf("?ReturnUrl"));

                            ctx.Response.Redirect(url + "?code=401");
                        }
                        // Or, directly using the following code:
                        //ctx.Response.Redirect("/Login/UserAccessDenied?code=401");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

The output like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Windows Authentication according to my appsettings (which I guess uses cookies?), I don't add any other Auth in my startup, I'm just using a custom [Authorize] attribute on my controllers, but this will work because I'm still using the `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` line