# MVC route returns 401 only if ReturnUrl parameter is in querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Within an MVC application, we're using a querystring parameter called `ReturnUrl` to track where the user came from, and where they return to after they finish with the current page/view. In addition, this same parameter is used when their session times out (for instance) and they are sent to the login page with the `ReturnUrl` parameter now containing the page they were just on.

The login redirect is handled correctly *as long as the URL they're coming from does not include the `ReturnUrl` parameter*. But if it does, then they are shown a hard 401 from IIS.

Example 1:

1. User is on http://example.com/Account/Edit
2. Session times out, then user hits refresh.
3. User is brought to login page with querystring parameter `ReturnUrl` properly set. **GOOD**

Example 2:

1. User is on http://example.com/Account/Edit?ReturnUrl=%2FSomething%2FElse%2F4
2. Session times out, then user hits refresh.
3. User is immediately shown IIS' 401 error page instead of being sent back to the login page. **BAD**

Note that the request *is* making it to the MVC handler:

[image: WHY ME?!]

I've debugged as best I can but the issue appears to occur within the MVC framework itself. If I change the `ReturnUrl` parameter to something else, `ReturnUrl2` for example, then the login redirect works fine.

What's so special about the word `ReturnUrl`?

Comment: *FULL DISCLOSURE* I was alerted by a coworker that I asked this same question two years ago. UGH. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116031/authorizeattribute-not-working-if-url-has-query-string

Comment: That's awesome! :)  ~Cheers!